# Accidental SSH to address

Tags: terminal, mac, network, ssh, hacking

Usually when I am doing some development on my mac, I ssh into a virtual machine running on my computer at a 172 address. However, when I was ssh ing into it today, I accidentally mistyped the address (forgot to add a 0 at the very end of the ip). However, once I accidentally ran this ssh command, it didn't immediately disconnect my computer, but rather, just had a blank output.

Now, to my knowledge, I believe that 172 addresses are private addresses. But I want to make sure, did running that ssh command on the mistyped IP address compromise my computer in any way?

Thank you all for all of your help

Comment: How would it, even if it were a real, routable, IP address?

Comment: 172.16.x.x through 172.31.x.x are private addresses, but if the second octet is below 16 or over 31, it's a public address.

Comment: It was 172.16.x.x, so I guess I am fine

Comment: ssh tends to try to connect for quite a while before giving up if it doesn't get a TCP connection. If  I understand what happened properly, my guess would be that it was just trying to connect & would eventually have timed out.

Answer (score 1):

172 are private to a certain subnet mask only. 172.16.-172.31 are private cname addresses.
ie.) if the address is 172.40.x.x will get you a public address...

Relax though, nothing is compromised. Just cuz you got a blank prompt doesn't actually mean anything.

You can always just open up another terminal window and issue

```
killall -9 ssh
killall -9 ssh-agent
```

then try again